# Displaying a Multi-Paged FlowDocument with repeating Headers

Tags: wpf, header, flowdocument

I am trying to add Headers / footers to a WPF `FlowDocument`. I Found a solution on the Internet [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/PimpedDocumentPaginator.aspx) that is using a custom Paginator Class to do this. Unfortunately this only works when printing out the Document, which is not what I intend to do. My Idea was to use a FlowDocumentPageReader or something similar with a custom paginator, but somehow I can't figure out how I would do that, maybe anyone can give me a hint in the right Direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are just displaying the FlowDocument and not printing it, you can implement headers and footers by creating a control template for the FlowDocumentPageViewer.

In the template, place textblocks above and below the DocumentPageView, and bind them to the appropriate values.

For example, if you want a page number:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=MasterPageNumber, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}" FontSize="14" FontWeight="Bold" />
```

and so on for title, etc.

You can wrap the textblocks and DocumentPageView with a border so the whole thing appears as one page.

Comment: Yes that works, thanks for the answer. In the meantime i have hacked some stuff together myself, but im gonna try this out right away!